# Find all paths in DAG from starting node

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to find all paths in DAG from selected node.

So I am randomly generating list of tuples that looks like:

```
glavnaLista = [(6, 7), (6, 15), (15, 16), (16, 21), (15, 9), (9, 13), (13, 4), (4, 1), (1, 5)]
```

From this list we can see that node "6" is starting point of graph

Now I am creating graph:

```
G = nx.DiGraph() 
    G.add_edges_from(glavnaLista)
```

[So it looks like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPdqX.png)

Now I am trying to find all paths (completed) from starting node with code:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, path=[]):

    path = path + [start]
    if start not in graph:
        return [path]
    paths = [path]
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                print (newpath)
                paths.append(newpath)        
    return paths
```

Result is list of all paths:

```
[[6], [6, 7], [6, 15], [6, 15, 16], [6, 15, 16, 21], [6, 15, 9], [6, 15, 9, 13], [6, 15, 9, 13, 4], [6, 15, 9, 13, 4, 1], [6, 15, 9, 13, 4, 1, 5]]
```

But my problem is that I don't need paths that are not full (not going to the ending node), my list should have only full paths:

```
[6, 7]
[6, 15, 9, 13, 4, 1, 5]
[6, 15, 16, 21]
```

My idea is to check if the node has both neighbours, and if it doesn't than add path to list but I am not sure how to implement this as I am fairly new to python.

Comment: Please add a `networkX` tag.

Comment: @Yonlif I did, thank You

Comment: Am I correctly understanding that you only want paths that go from a single node to leaf nodes, and you want to ignore paths that terminate at intermediate nodes?

Comment: @Joel Yeah, I needed every path that goes till the end from starting node and saving that path to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are trying to create is actually the tree created from [`BFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [`DFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) traversal over a [`DAG`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). You can do this by changing your code a bit.

First of all notice that you have some unnecessary code parts:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    paths = [path]
    for node in graph[start]:
        newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, path)
        for newpath in newpaths:
            print (newpath)
            paths.append(newpath)        
    return paths
```

Since we assume this is a `DAG` we can get rid of some conditions...

Now we want to generate the paths of a `DFS` traversal. The print here will print a path after each iteration but we would like to print the path after we reached an end.
So we will add a simple `if` statement to check if this is the end of the path and if it is we will print the path:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    paths = [path]
    if len(graph[start]) == 0:  # No neighbors
        print(path)
    for node in graph[start]:
        newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, path)
        for newpath in newpaths:
            paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```

Result:

```
[6, 7]
[6, 15, 16, 21]
[6, 15, 9, 13, 4, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Thank You, works like a charm, I added global variable and instead of printing path I am adding it to list.
I would vote You up but I am not allowed as I am new user.

Comment: Thanks! Enjoy Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an easy recursive function which utilize DFS + backtracking to do the job(if it's a DAG):

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start):
    if not graph[u]:
        return [[u]]
    paths = []
    for v in graph[u]:
        for v_path in find_all_paths(graph, v):
            paths.append([u] + v_path)
    return paths
```